# What is `this._newtext` in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I was just doing a ReactJS tutorial and I hit this:

```
renderForm() {
    return (
        <div className='note'>
            <form>
                <textarea ref={input => this._newText = input}/>
                <button><FaFloppy0/></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I understand the whole code, besides the ref part. I know it is a part of React Docs, so this is not my question.

My question is what is `this._newText`? Google is silent about it. I know it takes the value of the `textarea`.

But is it React specific thing? I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: It is not, it's probably some of your component's data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

If you provide a `ref` prop containing a function to an element in your render method (like in your example) that function will be called with the DOM node or React element.

When the textarea is rendered react will call the ref method passing in the textarea

```
ref={input => this._newText = input} // input == textarea ref on render
```

A typical way to access that `ref` outside the render function is to store it in an instance variable `this.someVar` which can be accessed throughout your component.

So to answer your question `this._newText` is just some instance variable storing the textarea `ref` (for all we know it could be named anything) and not anything React specific.

Comment: So `_newText` is just a name chosen by the tutorial author? Might as well be `potato`?

Comment: @alex3wielki Yup. It's just a variable name like any other